# Non interventional studies and statistical testing

Tags: observational-study

I have been part of an observational study which we also call a Non Interventional Study (NIS) which looks at a pool of subjects for whom we have 12 months data prior to starting a treatment and 12 months data after they started the treatment. The purpose is to compare the change in average value of an outcome before and after treatment. The sample of patients is approximately 200.

The analysis plan is being prepared and someone in the team is trying to insist that "since this is NIS, we will not be able to pre-specify any tests in the analysis plan". To me this doesn't make any sense because I'm sure the analysis plan can specify something like depending on whether the data on change before and after treatment is normally distributed we can do a paired sample t-test.

Do you agree with the statement that if a study is observational/NIS, it dictates whether or not you can plan any tests on it?? If yes, please can you also provide some references I can look at to understand why one cannot do a t-test on observational data?

Thank you!

Comment: You don't have to personally intervene. A study that includes a measurement before and after some treatment is not just observational. The treatment is the intervention.

Comment: I agree completely. However, this is a common term a lot of pharmaceuticals and CROs use to describe observational study. The idea is to "observe" how a treatment is done in common practice without providing any "intervention" in terms of treatment adherence, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in application of a t-test to this type of data lies in the interpretations of a t-test's corresponding p-value. Given that the null hypothesis is true and the model is correct, the p-value is the probability of observing at least as extreme results *due to chance alone*. The qualifier "due to chance alone" is particularly important in your setting. Importantly, this works in expectation for randomized treatments but is not always reasonable to assume for observational studies.

You can absolutely use something like a t-test, but you are assuming there are no time-varying variables that are systematically related to the treatment initiations and the outcome of interest. One simple counterexample is the season. Timing of treatment may systematic coincide with insurance plan deductible cycles and infectious diseases (e.g. influenza). If seasonal infectious diseases are related to the outcome systematically, then the assumption of "chance alone" no longer seems reasonable. In the usage of a t-test you are implicitly ruling out all these scenarios as explanations (i.e. there are **no** systematic differences for individuals in the before and after periods).

To summarize, t-tests are possible but if systematic differences occur they lose their interpretation. This is a major topic in causal inference with observational data. Robins's g-methods or Pearl's do-calculus are approaches to emulate randomization with observational data allowing the chance alone interpretation under their assumptions. You may find the target trial framework as a useful conceptual tool for further understanding this [Hernan & Robins 2016](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4832051/).